# How to encode nested arrays with JSONEncoder

Tags: ios, swift, jsonencoder

I am trying to encode four different arrays into a json format with JSONEncoder, but I am unable to convert the arrays. So, please help me out.
I am using swift 4, xcode 9 for iOS 11.

My arrays are:

```
var timeCart //dynamic data as string
var nameCart //dynamic data as string, ex. ["myNameOne", "myNameTwo", ...]
var quantityCart //dynamic data as Int, ex. [2, 3, 5, ...]
var priceCart //dynamic data as Int, ex. [82, 73, 65, ...]
```

my structs are:

```
struct OrderDetailJSON: Encodable {
    let allOrder: [AllOrder]
    let TaxDetials: TaxDetail

    struct AllOrder: Encodable {
        let date_time: String
        let item: String
        let name: String
        let price: String
    }

    struct TaxDetail: Encodable {
        let tax_per: String
        let tax_name: String
    }
}
```

I am trying to encode it like this, inside a table view

```
let orderDetailsJSON = OrderDetailJSON(allOrder: [.init(date_time: "\(quantityCart[indexPath.row])", item: "\(quantityCart[indexPath.row])", name: "\(nameCart[indexPath.row])", price: "\(priceCart[indexPath.row])")], TaxDetials: .init(tax_per: defaults.string(forKey: "STORE_TAX")!, tax_name: defaults.string(forKey: "STORE_TAX_NAME")!))
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(orderDetailsJSON)
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
            print("order_details :" + jsonString!)
        }catch{

        }
```

the output I am getting is:

```
order_details: {
  "TaxDetials": {
    "tax_per": "5",
    "tax_name": "CGST & SGST"
  },
  "allOrder": [
    {
      "date_time": "2",
      "name": "Manchurian",
      "item": "2",
      "price": "87"
    }
  ]
}order_details: {
  "TaxDetials": {
    "tax_per": "5",
    "tax_name": "CGST & SGST"
  },
  "allOrder": [
    {
      "date_time": "3",
      "name": "Paneer Tikka",
      "item": "3",
      "price": "150"
    }
  ]
}order_details: {
  "TaxDetials": {
    "tax_per": "5",
    "tax_name": "CGST & SGST"
  },
  "allOrder": [
    {
      "date_time": "2",
      "name": "snacks",
      "item": "2",
      "price": "54"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the output I am expecting is:

```
order_details: {
  "TaxDetials": {
    "tax_per": "5",
    "tax_name": "CGST & SGST"
  },
  "allOrder": [
    {
      "date_time": "2",
      "name": "Manchurian",
      "item": "2",
      "price": "87"
    },
    {
      "date_time": "3",
      "name": "Paneer Tikka",
      "item": "3",
      "price": "150"
    },
    {
      "date_time": "2",
      "name": "snacks",
      "item": "2",
      "price": "54"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The main problem are the 4 arrays. Use a suitable data model for you `cart` items.

Comment: let me try this.. thanks @vadian

Comment: Hey @vadian I am using dataModel now, getting same response.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your struct declarations (other than the fact that you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names - `taxPer` instead of `tax_per`, etc. and that your property names don't use the correct plural/singular forms).

The issue is that you are defining an `OrderDetailJSON` instance for each table view cell, while it seems that your `TaxDetails` should be the same for all cells in the table and you actually want to create a single `OrderDetailJSON` instance whose `allOrder` array property contains one `AllOrder` instance for each table view cell. You'll need to change the `allOrder` property to mutable for this to work.

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var orderDetails: OrderDetailJSON
    ...
    // You might need to use a different tableView function depending on your exact needs
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        orderDetails.allOrder[indexPath.row] = AllOrder(date_time: "\(quantityCart[indexPath.row])", item: "\(quantityCart[indexPath.row])", name: "\(nameCart[indexPath.row])", price: "\(priceCart[indexPath.row])")
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that `orderDetails` is initialized with the correct `TaxDetails` and that you preallocate the same number of elements to `allOrder` as many table view cells you'll have. You only need to convert the `orderDetails` to JSON once all cells have been filled up with information, you don't need to do it on a cell by cell basis.

Comment: it's throwing nil.

Comment: What's throwing `nil`? Since I've only included a skeleton code, please update your question with the code you use currently and pinpoint which line produces `nil`.

Comment: orderDetailJSON.allOrder[indexPath.row] = AllOrder(date_time: "\(quantityCart[indexPath.row])", item: "\(quantityCart[indexPath.row])", name: "\(nameCart[indexPath.row])", price: "\(priceCart[indexPath.row])")...   this line giving an error saying "found nil while unwrapping an optional value", I am using it inside tableView's 'cellForRowAt' function.  @david

Comment: @Neck then it seems you didn't actually initialize `orderDetails`. You should do that in an initializer or `viewDidLoad` depending on where exactly your data is coming from.